# Is there any Elastic Search appender for directly sending(storing) spring-boot application logs to Elastic Search without using ELK stack

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logback

We are planning to store our `(Spring-Boot)` application logs to `ElasticSearch`. I am aware of `ELK` stack, which uses `FileBeat + LogStash` to collect and process the logs.

**What is desired:** Have an appender in `logback.xml` to directly send the logs to `ElasticSearch`. The very basic idea is of having an appender like `File-Appenders` with the difference of target for storing logs being `ElasticSearch`.  At the same time, we **want to do it in asynchronous** manner. FYI, we are using `slf4j with logback` implementations for logging.

**More specifically:** We want to **remove the intermediators**:: `Logstash` or `Beats` as they will need more infra and may bring **unwanted overhead**. And having the process of sending logs to `ElasticSearch` in asynchronous way would be really great (so that application **does not suffer** latency due to logging).

**What I have already tried:**
[Send Spring Boot logs directly to LogStash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399354/send-spring-boot-logs-directly-to-logstash-with-no-file). But it seems of not much use, since it internally uses file appenders and the logs are then sent to `LogStash`.

Is there any such appenders available? Or maybe there is some workaround.

Comment: When you have multiple machines and multiple indexes for different app and environment logs, we may need logstash, else you can use filebeat as a shipping tool to Elasticsearch.

Comment: @JinnaBalu, even for a single app and single index in elastic, Is it possible to send logs to Elastic (app -> elastic) without writing logs -> to log file -> filebeat ->elastic.
Is there is no other way but to use logstash/filebeat?

Comment: but that will effect the performance of the application. Let springboot generate a logfile and forget, otherwise we give an extra thread to connect and process the log.